# Issues with Math functions in Visual Studio versions

Tags: c++

```
#include "string.h"
#include "math.h"

int main ()
{
    double result = (double)sqrt(2.3456F);
    unsigned char data[8]; //holds the bytes of the result

    memmove(data,&result,8);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d\n",data[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The above same code convert the sqrt() result to double and then stores in another double variable. Here the data holds the binary representation of the floating point number result.The same code when run on Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual C++ 2010 gives different results. Why is this so?

and one more thing is If the result had been a float then Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual C++ 2010 are giving the same value for the result.

Can any body sort out this??

Output with result variable being double::

with Visual C++ 6.0

byte representation of result variable-data::

```
[0] 196 'Ä'
[1] 12 ''
[2] 25 ''
[3] 254 'þ'
[4] 42 '*'
[5] 129 ''
[6] 248 'ø'
[7] 63 '?'
```

with Visual C++ 2010

data::

```
    [0] 0   unsigned char
    [1] 0   unsigned char
    [2] 0   unsigned char
    [3] 0   unsigned char
    [4] 43 '+'  unsigned char
    [5] 129 ''  unsigned char
    [6] 248 'ø' unsigned char
    [7] 63 '?'  unsigned char
```

Output with result variable being float::

with Visual C++ 6.0

```
    [0] 88 'X'  
    [1] 9 ' '   
    [2] 196 'Ä' 
    [3] 63 '?'
```

with Visual C++ 2010

I got the same binary value for  result variable as above.

Comment: This looks like `C`, not `C++` ?

Comment: @Paul R: this is still valid C++ and writing `int main()` is more idiomatic in C++ than in C where you would have written `int main(void)`.

Comment: you should rather use `printf("%hhu")` to print [unsigned chars](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: @Benoit: true, but he's using C #includes, C I/O and C typecasts - it might compile as C++ as well as C but idiomatically it's just plain C.

Comment: @Benoit: no, "%u" is all you need - unsigned chars get promoted to int.

Comment: It may be valid C++, but it's not idiomatic C++. Why the antique hackery, @Mahesh?

Answer (score 3):

Well, those 2 double values are almost the same.
First, you should understand how real numbers are represented in memory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

You can see, that first bytes of data, that a differ, just an lest significant part of fraction. Now lets make an experiment and study, what values we get for 2 numbers: one calculated from `sqrt`, second replaces first 4 bytes with 0. Lets print out double result as a number, fraction and bytes represenation

```
void show(double result)
{
    unsigned char * data = (unsigned char*)&result;
    unsigned long long fraction = *(unsigned long long int*)&result;

    fraction = fraction & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF;//52-bit mask!
    printf("result: %8f, with fraction %4lld. ", result, fraction);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%2X ",data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main ()
{
    double result = (double)sqrt(2.3456F);
    show(result);
    unsigned char * data = (unsigned char*)&result;
    memset(data, 0, 4);
    show(result);
    return 0;
}
```

For me output is

```
result: 1.531535, with fraction 2393821627440998. 66 5F C2  7 2B 81 F8 3F
result: 1.531535, with fraction 2393821497262080.  0  0  0  0 2B 81 F8 3F
```

As we can see, result is the same in both cases. The thing is that when exponent such a big value, changes in its lest significant bits does not produce any real change of the whole number.

Ok, why those values differ, while they are result of same calculation? It's because compiler. Different compilers produces slightly different code that produces slightly different result. But you should consider those 2 values *same*

EDIT: exact results of such a behavior
Well, you originally had a `float` number which gives you 23-bits precision. You calculated `sqrt` on that value and get `float` value that still has 23-bits precision. Than you converted it to double, that has 52-bits precision. So, you tried to extend precision, but you had no enough information to do it correctly, that is why you finished with `double` that still has `float` precision. And all bits lesser significant that 23rd get random values. If you  replace

```
(double)sqrt(2.3456F)
```

with

```
sqrt(2.3456)
```

you will get same result with both compilers, because you will use `double`- precision version of sqrt

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Here I am using the same Visual C++ compiler  except the version is different. I dont think version upgradation will cause this problem.

Comment: This is not a problem. It is just normal behavior. Real numbers represented not _exactly_. You have to live with that. You can see that my `gcc` generates 3rd representation by default, not one of 2 you mentioned

Comment: What my intention is I am reimplementing the code which is already existing in Visual C++ 6.0, on Visual C++ 2010.But the results are not matching because of this issue as the code involves so many operations on these values like exponentiation, sine.Is there any possibility to make them exactly same??